# Rails 3.1: controller variable avaliable in View layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Newbie Rails question.

I want to use some calculated value in layout for the view some. Value is calculated in controller every time page is requested. How can I do that?

Comment: views will automaticly inherit the instance variable from controller, just use it directly

Answer (score 3):

Use an instance variable, such as:

```rb
def index
  @my_calculated_value = calculate_value(param1, param2, ...)
end
```